# Error in function for my pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a program that takes in supposed to take in a number from a user `= (n)`, and create a thread to calculate the sum from 1 to n. I know that `((n+1)*n)/2` will give me the same result. When I run the program a thread is created but when I ask for the value of `'TotalSum'`, 0 is given instead of the calculation based on user input, why?

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <pthread.h>

void * thread_calc(void *);
int TotalSum=0;

int main()
{
    int iNumber,iCount;
    pthread_t tid, tid2;
    printf("Enter Number Up to Which You want to Sum :");
    scanf("%d",&iNumber);    
    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,thread_calc,(void *) iNumber);
    //pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,thread_calc,(void *)(iNumber+);




    printf("Thread %d running, Final Sum is : %d \n", tid,TotalSum);
    //printf("Thread %d running, Final Sum is : %d \n", tid2,TotalSum);
    //    return 0;
}

void *thread_calc(void *num)
{
    int *iNumber;
    iNumber=(int*)num;

    TotalSum = ((*iNumber + 1)* (*iNumber))/2;

    pthread_exit(NULL);    
}
```

My output: (For example, user enters 10)

```
Enter Number Up to Which You want to Sum :10
Thread 536937120 running, Final Sum is : 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main thread is not waiting for the thread to finish and you are not passing the correct argument to the thread function:

```
  pthread_create(&tid, NULL,thread_calc, &iNumber); //pass the address of iNumber
  pthread_join(tid, NULL); // main thread waits for the thread_calc to return
```

When the main thread exits the entire process dies. So, you need to wait for the thread to return with [`pthread_join()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html).
You are passing the `iNumber` itself as a pointer value to the thread function. But the thread function actually expects its argument to be 
a pointer (as you dereference the `iNumber` in `thread_calc()`).